# Google Web Toolkit - Flextable CSS

Tags: css, gwt, flextable

[a] [b] [c]

```
flextable1.setWidget(0, 0, new Label("a"));
flexTable1.setWidget(0, 1, new Label("b"));
flexTable1.setWidget(0, 2, new Label("c"));
```

I want set the orange background color only for column a. How to set? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with CSS style that is more manageable. *If you want to change it in future then you don't need to touch the JAVA code.*

**In this way you can benefit of Themes.**

JAVA:

```
// set style for first row and first column
flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setStyleName(0, 0,"yellowBackground");
```

CSS:

```
.yellowBackground {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    FlexTable flexTable1 = new FlexTable(); 

    Label a = new Label("a");

    flexTable1.setWidget(0, 0, a);
    flexTable1.setWidget(0, 1, new Label("b"));
    flexTable1.setWidget(0, 2, new Label("c"));

    //add your widget to your panel, I used RootPanel directly for this example.
    RootPanel.get().add(flexTable1);

    a.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("orange");
  }
```

Comment: Anyway if you share more info with us, we could give you a more complete answer, like using UiBinder, CssResources, or GQuery. Happy coding by the way.